# How to redirect nginx to non http without html headers

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm trying to redirect a url in nginx to a non http protocol such as test://123456 when i go to test.com/123456

I've tried the following rewrite:
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ test://$1  permanent;

and it works however the weird part that it adds html/body headers which mess up my code, is there any way to do without the html headers or any other recommended way to to such rewrite?

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently  
Server: nginx/1.1.19 
Date: Tue, 30 Apr 2013 14:14:47 GMT 
Content-Type: text/html 
Content-Length: 185  
Connection: keep-alive
Location: test://123456
```

---

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.1.19</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not weird, this is how it’s supposed to be.

> [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) specifies that the entity bodies you want to remove should be present.
>
> > *10.3.2 301 Moved Permanently*
> >
> > The new permanent URI SHOULD be given by the Location field in the response. Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the new URI(s).
>
> and...
>
> > *10.3.3 302 Found*
> >
> > *The temporary URI SHOULD be given by the Location field in the response. Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the new URI(s).*
>
> SHOULD, in this context, is defined in [RFC 2119](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt):
>
> > *This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a particular item, but the full implications must be understood and carefully weighed before choosing a different course.*

Answer taken from [NGINX 301 and 302 serving small nginx document body. Any way to remove this behaviour?](https://serverfault.com/a/423685/131878)

---

Of course you can still do it, one possibility would be to proxy the request and change the requests method from GET to HEAD. That should ensure that only HTTP headers are sent.

This is untested, but it should be a good starting point:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;
    return 301 test://$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_method HEAD;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

Also from interest in this context [NGINX convert HEAD to GET requests](https://serverfault.com/questions/347663).